# Python open, multiple print

Tags: python

I want to do 10 print of file.read()
But, it only gives me 1 line with text and 9 lines with blank text

```
file = open('text.txt', 'r')
a = 1
while a < 10 :
    print(file.read())
    a = a + 1
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6Us6.png)

Comment: why not store contents in a variable and print it 10 times? `contents = file.read()` and print contents 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `file` object, once `read()` will not yield the same text again upon the next `read()`. You need to rewind the file back to the beginning to make `read()` work again. Use `seek(0)`

```
file = open('text.txt', 'r')
a = 1
while a < 10 :
    print(file.read())
    a = a + 1
    file.seek(0)
```

If your file contents are not changing between iterations, you can read the contents into a string outside the loop and print that 10 times in the loop.